# Existence of solutions of divergence equation on manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(\mathcal{M},g)$ be a $4$-dimensional Lorentzian manifold with corresponding Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{g}$. Furthermore, let $f_{\mu}\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ for $\mu=0,\dots,3$. Does the equation

$$\nabla^{g}_{\mu}u=f_{\mu}$$

for $u\in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ has a solution, or if not in general, which assumption I have to put on the inhomogeneous term $f$? I am not interested in uniqueness, just existence.

What I have tried so far is the following: Contracting with another $\nabla_{\mu}$ in front and contracting yields

$$\square^{g} u=(\nabla^{g})^{\mu}f_{\mu}$$

where $\square^{g}:=(\nabla^{g})^{\mu}\nabla^{g}_{\mu}$ denotes the d'Alembertian. Since $(\nabla^{g})^{\mu}f_{\mu}$ is smooth, this equation does have a solution, since it is hyperbolic. However, this only works in one direction, since a solution of the d'Alembertian equation above does not necessarily solve my original PDE.

Any help or reference is appreciated.

Comment: The Levi-Civitia connection actons on vector fields, but it acts on scalar function in your case. What do you mean by $\nabla^g u$? I strongly feel like this is a theorem like "every vector field is a gradient field", which is not true.

Comment: Well, it is a little bit an abuse of notation. Levi-Civita connection acting on vector field is just the usual partial derivative, i.e. $\nabla^{g}_{i}u=\partial_{i}u$.